# How to use range in a loop: Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This will print out 10+ links, how do I limit it to only fetch the first 3 links?

```
def getlinks(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=iphone&sp=EgQIBRAB')

        the_links = self.driver.find_elements(By.ID, "video-title")
        sleep(5)

        for link in the_links:
            self.links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

        for link in self.links:
            print(link)
```

Comment: you point directly to index positon of the link using :  `for link in self.links[:3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `for link in self.links[:3]`.

You can also use the equivalent expression `for link in self.links[0:3]`.